# How do i get the url for the mysite host from powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, my-site, user-profile-service

I need the url of the mysite in SharePoint 2010 server. In my farm i only have one MySite host (and one corresponding user profile service) configured.

I need the information on one of the farm servers and i'm using powershell for my script.

Comment: In response to ToddKlindt: https://twitter.com/#!/ToddKlindt/statuses/149520404845838336

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the sharepoint Management Shell you can execute the following script. Replace the url with one of the application url's your are running on:

```
$mySiteUrl = "http://portal.contoso.com"
$sc = Get-SPServiceContext($mySiteUrl)
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($sc)
$upm.MySiteHostUrl
```

If no url is available take one from Get-SPWebApplication if all web apps are using the same UPS.

Answer (score 2):

For simple farms you can use the following

```
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager([Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Personal site for a user profile you can get that from the UserProfileManager.UserProfile.PublicUrl.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.publicurl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one Web Application in your Server Farm you can also get it this way:

```
# Get the info from the Content Database
$myContentDb = Get-SPContentDatabase
# Get the Web Application
$myWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication
```

With these objects you can get the URL and more information on the Web Application. I use this as a precursor to get the information from the Server Farm so I can dismount the content database in preparation for restores in our test environment.